# Do compilers take advantage of the indeterminate sequencing of function arguments?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, operator-precedence, order-of-execution

Okay, I'm aware that the standard dictates that a C++ implementation may choose in which order arguments of a function are evaluated, but are there any implementations that actually 'take advantage' of this in a scenario where it would actually affect the program?

Classic Example:

```cpp
int i = 0;
foo(i++, i++);
```

Note: I'm not looking for someone to tell me that the order of evaluation can't be relied on, I'm well aware of that. I'm only interested in whether any compilers actually do evaluate out of a left-to-right order because my guess would be that if they did lots of poorly written code would break (rightly so, but they would still probably complain).

Comment: Please note that `foo(i++,i++)` invokes undefined behavior, because `i` is incremented more than one without any intervening any sequence point.

Comment: clang uses left to right evaluation.

Comment: When using C++ you should always use a static code checker. Anyone worth its salt will point out this error.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It depends on the argument type, the called function's calling convention, the archtecture and the compiler. On an x86, the [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#pascal) calling convention evaluates arguments left to right whereas in the C calling convention ([__cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks(VS.80).aspx)) it is right to left. Most programs which run on multiple platforms do take into account the calling conventions to skip surprises.

There is a nice [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/08/48616.aspx) on Raymond Chen' blog if you are interested. You may also want to take a look at the [Stack and Calling](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Stack-and-Calling.html) section of the GCC manual.

**Edit:** So long as we are splitting hairs: My answer treats this not as a language question but as a platform one. The language standard does not gurantee or prefer one over the other and leaves it as **unspecified**. Note the wording. It does not say this is undefined. Unspecified in this sense means something you cannot count on, non-portable behavior. I don't have the C spec/draft handy but it should be similar to that from my n2798 draft (C++)

> Certain other aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this International Standard as unspecified (for example, order of evaluation of arguments to a function). Where possible, this International Standard defines a set of allowable behaviors. These define the nondeterministic aspects of the abstract machine. An instance of the abstract machine can thus have more than one possible execution sequence for a given program and a given input.

Comment: Just to be clear, pascal/cdecl decides whether the arguments are *passed* left-to-right or right-to-left -- they can still be *evaluated* in any order. (Though due to register pressure it's likely that they'll be evaluated in the same order as they're passed.)

Comment: Wrong: C arguments are pushed onto the stack right to left. But the order they are evaluated is undefined.

Comment: @Martin York: When did I say that the order is well-defined?

Comment: @Martin York: By C I had meant the C calling convention. Edited post.

Comment: @dirkgently: Your answer says that the calling convention determines evaluation order. As Martin York says, that's not true, it only defines the order in which they're pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @jalf: I didn't intend to. I'll clarify.

Comment: I've never met a compiler in the wild that evaluated the arguments in a different order than it pushed them on the stack. I've looked at a lot of generated code over quite a few years of embedded systems work. This is still a highly implementation-specific detail, of course.

Comment: @Martin York: The order is unspecified and not undefined.

Comment: RBerteig: I have met such a compiler.

Comment: The '98 C++ standard 5.2.2.8

The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is entered. The order of evaluation of the postfix expression and the argument expression list is unspecified.

Comment: Particularly random use-case for knowing this: gmock `EXPECT`ations. I had a function call `foo(bar.getData(), bar.getLen())` and had an `InSequence` gmock test where I did `EXPECT_CALL(mockBar, getData()).WillOnce(...); EXPECT_CALL(mockBar, getLen()).WillOnce(...));` and this explains why my tests were failing.

Answer (score 7):

I found answer in [c++ standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf).

Paragraph 5.2.2.8:

> The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is entered. The order of evaluation of the postfix expression and the argument expression list is
>   unspecified.

In other words, It depends on compiler only.

Comment: Um, not responsive to the question.

Answer (score 6):

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598148/is-it-legal-to-use-the-increment-operator-in-a-c-function-call)

It's not an exact copy of your question, but my answer (and a few others) cover your question as well.

There are very good optimization reasons why the compiler might not just choose right-to-left but also interleave them.

The standard doesn't even guarantee a sequential ordering. It *only* guarantees that when the function gets called, all arguments have been fully evaluated.

And yes, I have seen a few versions of GCC do exactly this. For your example, foo(0,0) would be called, and i would be 2 afterwards. (I can't give you the exact version number of the compiler. It was a while ago - but I wouldn't be surprised to see this behavior pop up again. It's an efficient way to schedule instructions)

Comment: common subexpression elimination is the main reason for optimization re-ordering.  Remember that argument evaluation and parameter passing are allowed to be different, even though many compilers treat them identically.

Answer (score 6):

All arguments are evaluated. Order not defined (as per standard). But all implementations of C/C++ (that I know of) evaluate function arguments from **right to left**.  *EDIT: CLang is an exception (see comment below).*

I believe that the right-to-left evaluation order has been very very old (since the first C compilers). Certainly way before C++ was invented, and most implementations of C++ would be keeping the same evaluation order because early C++ implementations simply translated into C.

There are some technical reasons for evaluating function arguments right-to-left. In stack architectures, arguments are typically pushed onto the stack. In C/C++, you can call a function with more arguments than actually specified -- the extra arguments are simiply ignored. If arguments are evaluated left-to-right, and pushed left-to-right, then the stack slot right under the stack pointer will hold the last argument, and there is no way for the function to get at the offset of any particular argument (because the actual number of arguments pushed depends on the caller).

In a right-to-left push order, the stack slot right under the stack pointer will always hold the first argument, and the next slot holds the second argument etc. Argument offsets will always be deterministic for the function (which may be written and compiled elsewhere into a library, separately from where it is called).

Now, right-to-left push order does not mandate right-to-left evaluation order, but in early compilers, memory is scarce. In right-to-left evaluation order, the same stack can be used in-place (essentially, after evaluating the argument -- which may be an expression or a funciton call! -- the return value is already at the right position on the stack). In left-to-right evaluation, the argument values must be stored separately and the pushed back to the stack in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I saw differences was between VS2005 and GCC 3.x on an x86 hardware in 2007.
So it's (was?) a very likely situation. So I never rely on evaluation order anymore. Maybe it's better now.

Comment: Oh? That's very good to know. Thanks.

Currently the only compilers I use are VC 08 and ICC 11. I should probably start testing my code in GCC too.

Comment: ICC goes great lengths to be as compatible with VS as possible. Good folks those Intel people :)

Comment: VS doesn't guarantee an evaluation order either. They've changed how they evaluate function arguments before, and there's no reason why they wouldn't do so again. It is not something you should rely on.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that most modern compilers would attempt to interleave the instructions computing the arguments, given that they are required by the C++ standard to be independent and thus lack any interdependencies.  Doing this should help to keep a deeply-pipelined CPU's execution units full and thereby increase throughput.  (At least I would expect that a compiler that claims to be an optimising compiler would do so when optimisation flags are given.)

Answer (score 2):

TL:DR: no, GCC and clang in practice don't choose an eval order based on what would lead to more efficient asm, in cases of unsequenced or indeterminatedly-sequenced expressions with.  (Even for expressions *without* side-effects at least in some cases.)

---

First of all, `foo(i++, i++)` has undefined behaviour in C++14 and earlier, with two unsequenced modifications of `i`, no different from `i++ + i++` as far as the ISO standard is concerned; real implementations might happen to do something consistent in the case of function args.

C++17 changed function args from unsequenced to *indeterminately sequenced*, so it has to be either `arg1 = i++; arg2 = i++; foo(arg1,arg2)` or the reverse, at the compiler's choice.  *[What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)*

---

GCC and clang fail hard at optimizing based on choice of evaluation order in unsequenced or indeterminately-sequenced cases, missing even some very basic stuff like saving 3 separate local vars across a call vs. just saving the `a+b+c` result for `return baz(a+b+c, foo(x));`; see `quux` in the [**Godbolt link**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIABspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcYl2mA4ZQgRMxARZPn4BldUCtfUERRHRsQm2dQ1NOa1D3aG9pf3xAJS2qF7EyOwcoQQA1FFMAF4Q66Qb67MmAMxWGgCCJlfrGynrsQr7ghsAVEmHd28AjicA7BdLhsQRsAPRg%2B7ETAAWjc1msXH%2BhzEeCYaSMGwA7otaOgtpgNnIbBsFKhsYS0F48Rt0OSoqgCAgNrRUEx0AoCfxoRtMIQELFSURoTdgaDoQQlgwtrsIAjLL9DvKLB8TudRSZ/gARDVmU5YGhhDYAJWwQgAKsaAJJuc3gt4bBjk6EKAjEPAOd5g0UQ8z6zCGwmmi3W20bAD64Zdbo9BA1t1eD0ETzML026B8LAAnlwvq83sHLTa7T885sC2ai2GkgCLCCIRsfhsmYx7qLQeCwXgqBsIEkzjrTlq/hsJVKNhozkCO2PiNLtntlYqNkua1OOxvN/XIU2W9KkiCYaSqgJ8fVgBtkAYFALOVj%2BUcGGgWKFgBrtfHLnckwQnqc0%2B8hahnanyPummY5mWgGVsBja1qCDYHnujbtghXY9n2A4DiOs7SpO6pXDOmCSnOMqLpY1jLquap1ludHbo2zYCvuGxHjQxCuhs56Xtet7Yg%2BoTPq%2B746lcn5%2Bt2E4%2BmCkZMAQMZRF4v6RlASRLJgswnFcEKyfJ7qKcp4ZQGgDCuppDFutSWb3OpGxUF4T6OAIop3PwqBpjRLmvNsxAAUwswroCqG4XZqDuUw1hmAF1gbAArO8oXkhA/lTiJn53D5qZ3P5gXTqOxHjgu1BhclkXzHFCVub2/meWJH5iQmmyqKljUysQ/7ZdFQWEflJHzrKzWWAEFUOlVECqJpLXXPV1wNV%2B3n1JIfldXlIVFW543KuVY2DVYliTQR02ibN82bD5sXLblwUFaRRW7dYhz3ft66dhsADibhuFxDD4lehgXoJJDQg4tDWVi9TSkwDJKRsDlKD8XiMCs%2BKYAAbq2oQbPCFGWEiGwsBgmAAHSofRZMdg2VoEGAHCcq6dC0I6jLYggckbFmizYoYBCHC2XEOF4YhccQwCckk6JKL9uL4vgVBULEYBgGlc0NmktCg5eqAsEkdBPKSTDo1xhxRCiP2Xse4vEHJmAa0wyDEKknJMJeYiM0QiUQFpp2Nl4XiqH5UEm2Bl61qTvWFbKEWWFE1jIIcG0TbVR3pa8CN%2B1lrxMIHUHIKHPUMSQ/FMhspwbIyArEBswCstsjOo/UnKFz%2BsQwlg0JUJyTJsxtAUvsACCbIXfcD0zmwE7LWZh2tsoJ%2BVUcWDHli51NmrHX6rjdqKHDzLQnCxbwfgcFopCoJw2N7XWZJLCsK56jwpAEJo2/zAA1v48REwAnBoZixackhcC4KcDQ8QNCSFOKcfQnBJAHyfifTgvAFAgA0A/J%2B8w4CwCQM%2BHW9AyAUAgNg3WcRgBAICFgVGHpMAADU8CYCxAAeSSIwTg98aC0F/BxSgUQ4FRFCPULMLDeC8OYMQLM9CojaCqI/bgvBnxsEEPQhgoM4FYEUsANwrskEyNIFgFg/1xBH14PgYGjh0ZaOPpgVQVQlKrHvo8Xehj9B4CiFbURHgsBwJjCwQR8wqAGFFjQuhjDmHaP4IIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1CON0LmAwRgUDKicVEJBkB5ioCSE5UynAYT0NLjCAA6q7Virp0ADmAAwLwyokS8FQOjYg7osBZM9rYG2UiMguB%2BiMPwuZgiTBKGUPQKQ0j5IGeM/I%2BSeijP6LmNo%2BTOjDE8M0PQyyajjHmX0OISzxjTIOV0XZ0x9nzCvssKJO896wMcafDgGxVAAA54gwniJIKuyBkAbCAUTMwvZcCEELn6LgsxeDSK0JpUgb89REw0J/f4kh4ixWea8z%2BpxP6xWRA4mBpBD7HweYg5BqDDHoJgIgFAWscGxHIJQQhuCQD1BYCQ04ZgUHkMoYEhhTDD6sLoBwpBEBuGOOEfwwRpAxWiPEZIhwEq5GMAIIo5RjjVFeHUZoiVuj9GrGPsYnpZi4GWOsb%2BCV9i4G0Gca4rM7jdUQvdN4mRvj/EKG5cEvlvAwnCFEOIaJXq4lqDgboAIKTjDpMtZk%2BAOS8kZC0UUkpVSal1Iaf8ViLBkBqQHGgBoliYRMD/k0lpbTMAdIud09ofgICuCOYEH6pyxm5gmQUTI6yciNtmRketiyun2BWYc1tgye09I6DskZezNn9uyIO10Jyx1nIkBcxYVyF1QI4PvfFcCHkbEuMaAAsu9T6vzTj/PhYC/Awpb6nDBRCtBr9/CxVXXiglTSEG2BJZC7epAMGUoZbS/Bv64h/SMEiDQuZOUrDdbyiVbDBVcJ4Xw0REqpViIkVI%2BVWt5FKqUQI1VmA1EaPVlo%2B%2B2qjAGL1XgExeBDWOONcgGxZrkwOOPhG61trPEOp8XwF1kGQmsNkBE310h/VKEDYkkAkDQ1pJxjYCNpaT4xoEHG4prFynq0qQQapQ5an1Ok4AwtsRi1ya2c4Kt/SB16GGcUcd7bJkZBrU2uZc6G1Dorasxo5mlnlr7bOqz87jlrKnROnzUwG2Luvtc1d67n3wMeS8t5HyeL/V%2Bf8eFRMuBnuBZXUF4LSVQrvb/R9dzCWvqQSgj90KHFmCKy%2BjgN6yXzBaWkZwkggA%3D%3D%3D) that has code for other parts of this question.  (And that's not even a correctness issue, just implementation details that gives the same result in the abstract machine either way.)

[GCC bug#70408 *reusing the same call-preserved register would give smaller code in some cases*](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70408) shows a case of unsequenced evaluation that doesn't have UB, where a different choice of evaluation order could let the compiler save/restore fewer registers if it was smart enough.  Apparently per Andrew Pinski's reply, teaching GCC to consider a different eval order would be really hard, at least for function calls.

```cpp
// __attribute__((const)) //  optional: promises no side-effects and not even reading anything except args
int foo(int);  // not inlineable

int bar(int a) {
  return foo(a+2) + 5 * foo (a);
}
```

```
# first function args goes in RDI
foo_gcc:  # current GCC13.2 is the same as GCC6 when I reported the missed-optimization
    pushq   %rbp
    pushq   %rbx               # save two call-preserved regs
    movl    %edi, %ebx
    leal    2(%rdi), %edi        # lea is worse than  add $2, %edi; separate missed opt
    subq    $8, %rsp           # and adjust the stack again for alignment
    call    foo                # foo(a+2)
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    movl    %eax, %ebp
    call    foo                # foo(a)
    addq    $8, %rsp
    leal    (%rax,%rax,4), %eax   # eax = 4*eax + eax = 5*eax
    popq    %rbx
    addl    %ebp, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

vs. by hand, calling in the other order and using LEA to add while copying.  (`lea` into the same register is slightly worse than `add`-immediate on some CPUs, e.g. Intel before Ice Lake, but it's always worth using when it saves one or more instruction, even just a `mov`.)

```
foo_handwritten:
    push    %rbx
    lea     2(%rdi), %ebx          # stash ebx=a+2
    call    foo                    # foo(a)
    mov     %ebx, %edi
    lea     (%rax,%rax,4), %ebx    # reuse ebx to stash 5*foo(a)
    call    foo                    # foo(a+2)
    add     %ebx, %eax
    pop     %rbx
    ret
```

---

**If we look at just function-arg order** including possible side-effects, either on different variables to avoid UB, or in C++17 so they're indeterminately sequenced, we can get UB-free code that's meaningful to talk about.

Stuff like `foo(++*p, ++*q)` is interesting: pre-C++17, a compiler could assume `int *p,*q` don't alias each other, since that would lead to UB from unsequenced side-effects.  So e.g. it could do both loads before either increment and store<sup>1</sup>.  (Especially useful when scheduling instructions for an in-order machine to better hide load latency.)  But it looks like compilers didn't actually do that.

In calling conventions with register args, the outgoing args need to ends up in the same registers where we received incoming args. (Also true with stack args, but in that case you'd have to load into registers before use anyway, and then overwrite the incoming args before a tail-call jump as well as storing to the pointed-to object.)

So a function like this will need some register copying instructions, since it can't just load `*p` into RDI (on x86-64 for example), it needs the pointer around afterwards to store the incremented value back.  But it also needs the incremented value to end up in the register that was originally holding the pointer.

```cpp
int baz(int,int);      // not visible to the compiler for inlining

int pointers(int *p, int *q){   // in RDI, RSI in the x86-64 System V calling convention
    return baz(++*p, ++*q);     // int args in EDI, ESI, the low 32 bits of RDI,RSI
}
```

This problem is symmetric; neither evaluation order has any advantage.  And each dereferenced value has to land in the register that held *its* pointer, rather than a different arg. `baz(++*q, ++*p)` to make them opposite would allow saving an instruction, but it's still symmetric so whichever one we evaluate first, the register we want to eval into is occupied.

We can add a dummy argument so incoming and outgoing args only overlap in one register, and order them so neither case needs the integer in the same register that held a pointer to it.  (Because that would necessitate either copying the pointer or loading somewhere else and then copying the integer after the store.)

```cpp
// test cases that allow more efficient asm with one eval order than the other
int pointers2(int dummy1, int *q, int *p){  // q then p
    return baz(++*q, ++*p);                 // q then p - 2nd arg clashes with incoming
}

int pointers3(int *p, int dummy1, int *q){  // p then q
    return baz(++*q, ++*p);                 // q then p - 1st arg clashes with incoming
}
```

With this setup, one evaluation order can avoid needing any extra register-copy instructions.  The other one can't, because it wants to evaluate `++*q` or `++*p` into a register that's still holding the other pointer.  Compilers appear to use a fixed evaluation order, or at least not using their freedom to choose to their advantage.

GCC on x86-64 goes right-to-left, making `pointers2` worse because it wants to compute the outgoing `++*p` arg while the incoming `q` arg is still live in RSI.  **GCC targeting ARM goes left-to-right for both these functions**, handling `pointers2` better.  So it's not always consistent even within the same compiler, and may be due to some arbitrary internals.  None of these involve any stack args, although historically only x86 calling convention GCC supported was 32-bit x86 with purely stack args, which could perhaps explain right-to-left being baked-in to GCC's x86 internals.  (I haven't tested other cases to see if it's always consistent, but some older answers here report that it was.)

Clang for x86-64 goes left-to-right (like ARM GCC), so `pointers2` avoids any wasted instructions; RSI is no longer needed by the time it's ready to compute `++*p` there.

```
# Actual GCC13 code-gen for the good version
# p in RDI, q in RDX
pointers3(int*, int, int*):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]          # *p
        lea     esi, [rax+1]                  # 1 + *p   But LEA saves the day
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], esi          # ++*p

        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]          # *q 
        lea     edi, [rax+1]                  # eval into EDI, the first arg
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], edi

        jmp     baz(int, int)                 # tailcall
```

It could have loaded into ESI in the first place and used `add` instead of `lea` to copy+add<sup>2</sup>.   But no wasted `mov` instructions; GCC's evaluation right-to-left evaluation order happened to be good for that one.  Unlike the other function:

```
# Actual GCC13 code-gen for the sub-optimal version
# q in RSI, p in RDX
pointers2(int, int*, int*):
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]     # load *p
        mov     rax, rsi               ##### copy q to RAX, this is the insn we could avoid
        lea     esi, [rcx+1]             # eval ++*p into outgoing 2nd arg reg
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], esi     # and store it back to *p

        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rax]     # using the copy of q
        lea     edi, [rcx+1]             # eval ++*q into 1st arg
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edi

        jmp     baz(int, int)            # tailcall
```

Picking the other order to evaluate args would have avoided the `mov rax, rsi` instruction the way `pointers3` did, saving code-size and letting out-of-order exec see a little bit farther (since it won't take up an entry in the ROB = Reorder Buffer.)

```
# Hand-written version that GCC *could* have made
#  with different semantics if p==q.  Or equivalent with __restrict
# q in RSI, p in RDX
pointers2(int, int*, int*):
        mov     edi, [rsi]
        add     edi, 1                # eval ++*q into 1st arg
        mov     [rsi], edi

        mov     esi, [rdx]
        add     esi, 1                # eval ++*p into outgoing 2nd arg
        mov     [rdx], esi

        jmp     baz(int, int)         # tailcall
```

(`DWORD PTR` is implied by the other operand being a 32-bit register so I prefer to omit it.  That's just a formatting difference between the examples, the key difference is that this is 7 instructions total instead of 8, and 3 bytes smaller in code-size.  The instructions I used are all at least as cheap on all CPUs.)

Generally one `mov` doesn't matter in a whole program, but compilers should still not waste instructions.  This example should be enough to conclude that GCC and clang don't look for such optimizations in general, even for cases where there might be more savings.  (Like with function calls as args.)

---

#### Footnote 1:

In C++17 the `p==q` case would avoid UB, but the compiler's choice of which increment do do first would affect the function args.  **So you shouldn't write code like `baz(++*p, ++*q)` unless you know they're not equal.**

You can even make this promise to the compiler with `int *__restrict p, int *__restrict q`, or if they're different types then with the default `-fstrict-aliasing`, GCC and clang will infer they don't alias.  e.g. `int *p, long long *q`.

`__restrict` doesn't help with the missed-optimization test-case, although GCC will then do both loads before either store, always on ARM or just for `pointer2` on x86-64.  In-order exec is common on ARM cores, so hiding load latency is more useful.  Even on x86-64, stores with unknown addresses (because out-of-order exec doesn't have the address ready yet) are better if you can wait until after loads, so the CPU doesn't have to predict whether it needs to store-forward or not.

GCC's ARM code-gen probably would have been better with the first load as the first instruction, instead of copying a pointer to another register; `-mcpu=cortex-a53` vs. `-mcpu=cortex-a76` does make that different tuning / instruction-scheduling choice.  Also, it ends up spending an extra `mov` in both versions of the function for the non-aliasing case.  That could be worth it to avoid load latency bottlenecks on in-order cores, if it's unavoidable, but I'm not sure it is. e.g.

###### This part is getting into the weeds of instruction scheduling for ARM, kind of off topic

```
@ hand-written for the version with  __restrict  pointers
@ GCC13.2  starts with  mov r3, r0  then 2 loads / 2 adds / 2 stores
pointers3(int*, int, int*):
        ldr     r1, [r0]
        ldr     r3, [r2]       @ Eventually want it in R0, but load elsewhere
        adds    r1, r1, #1     @ first use is 2 insns after the load, same as GCC
        str     r1, [r0]       @ store right after add; GCC left a gap
        adds    r0, r3, #1     @ adds into a different low reg is still a 16-bit instruction with small-enough immediate
        str     r0, [r2]
        b       baz(int, int)
```

This might still be pretty decent for in-order ARM.  The second LDR and first ADDS can go through the pipeline in the same cycle since they're independent.   But not the STR in the same cycle as the ADDS that produces its input, unless the memory stage is later in the pipeline than exec and a superscalar CPU supports that forwarding.  (P5 Pentium didn't, IIRC.)
Then the next cycle the first STR and second ADDS can go, then the second STR and the B tailcall jump.

This doesn't seem much if any worse than GCC's mov/load/load ; then after load results are ready, adds/adds ; store/store (or probably separate since most pipelines won't have 2 store units) ; branch.  Or maybe it is and my instruction-saving version would only be worth it when tuning for OoO exec cores like `-mcpu=cortex-a76`.  Regardless, if we need a `mov`, I assume it would be better to it after the 2 loads, before the 2 stores, to get more done before stalling to wait for load-use latency.  Or maybe load / pointer-copy / load so we can still dual-issue on the first cycle on a pipeline with only one load unit.  Anyway, getting off topic here into ARM instruction scheduling.

Fun fact: this scheduling is the same pattern clang uses for RISC-V: load/load / add / store / add / store. Clang for other ISAs still goes with left-to-right eval order. (At least into registers; I didn't check with so many args that it would need a few stack args. Hopefully it would eval stack args first so it has spare registers to eval other reg args. Or at least schedule the instructions that way, if they're independent.)

If you put `if (p==q) return 0;` into the functions, even GCC for x86-64 will do both loads first for `pointers2`.  (Still with an extra `mov` which it could have avoided by doing an `lea esi, [rax+1]` after the first store, instead of `add eax, 1` before and `mov esi, eax` after.)

---

##### Footnote 2: GCC uses LEA where it could have used `add`

With `return baz(*q <<= 7, *p *= 4);` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zs8c965vY)), GCC uses `lea     esi, [0+rax*4]` which is 7 bytes (opcode + modrm + SIB + disp32=0), which is 4 bytes longer than if it had loaded into ESI in the first place for `shl esi, 2`.

But it does load into EDI directly so it can `sal edi, 7`.  And with `*q *= 12385, ++*p`, it does use a memory-source imul-immediate to load-and-multiply into EDI.

I guess its cost model incorrectly thinks that if LEA is possible at all, it's as cheap as anything else, so register allocation doesn't bother to work harder to get the inputs into the right register.  A simple change to that heuristic might make worse code in other cases, though, like not using LEA in a case where it *could* save instructions, depending on what the actual heuristics are.