# Problem in incrementing

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

I have a variable declared like this:

```
int j=0;
```

When I write:

```
cout<<j++<<" "<<j++<<" "<<j++<<"\n";
```

I receive this output:

```
2 1 0
```

I expect to receive this output:

```
0 1 2
```

Could you explain the result?

Comment: posting the full source code would be beneficial

Comment: There was a reasonable amount of source code, but it wasn't formatted properly.

Comment: That is because you are using recursion with the ++ Operator :D

Comment: The source was in the source for the question. It was just incorrectly formatted. Edited.

Comment: @mouviciel: Our edits trod on each other. Mine also made the language a bit cleaner - I rolled yours back and then improved mine again (in terms of formatting). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Actually, I prefer your english than mine!

Comment: Would you mind sharing what compiler you're using? You've got me intrigued now.

Answer (score 10):

The spec says that if you modify the same variable more than once within the same sequence point, the result is "undefined".

Sequence points are between ; (and also , is a sequence point, not sure if there are others).

What you're trying is the same as the better known trivia question, "what's the value of x after the second assignment?"

```
int x;
x = 0;
x = x++;
```

The answer is "undefined".

Comment: In the users code, there is a sequence point at each use of the << operator, because these are really function calls.

Comment: I believe the answer is correct, but the reason is somewhat subtle. My understanding is that all the increments can happen before any of the function sequence points, but I'm going to ask exactly that question separately and we can fight it out there :-)

Comment: @Neil. That's not totally accurate. The only restriction on function calls is that all parameters must be fully evaluated before the function is called. With chained functions like this it is a single expression and all calls are all between the same sequence points.

Answer (score 6):

This code is equivalent to

```
... operator<<( operator<<( operator<<( operator<<(cout,j++), " " ), j++ ), "\n" ); ...
```

Though order of function call is given, order of parameters evaluation is not.
So there is no guarantees which j++ is evaluated first. There are modifications of j without sequence points between them, so you see result of Undefined Behaviour.

**[Edit1]** There is inaccuracy in previous. operator<<(int) is a member function of basic_ostream. Denote operator<<(int) as f, operator<<(ostream&,const char*) as g. Then we have

```
...g(f(j++)," ").f(j++)...
```

Order of evaluation still can be: eval(j++) -> eval(j++) -> **sequence point** -> call(f) -> **sequence point** -> call(g) -> **sequence point** -> call(f). This is because of following quote from standard [expr.4]:

> Except where noted, the order of
>   evaluation of operands of individual
>   operators and subexpressions of
>   individual expressions, and the order
>   in which side effects take place, is
>   unspecified

Comment: That would be true if operator<< were always implemented as a non-member function. For some compilers it is a member of basic_ostream.

Answer (score 3):

This is because your compiler is likely evaluating the equation from right to left.

check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c) question for more info.

**Edit:**
Tested on g++ 4.4.0

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
int j = 0;
std::cout << j++ << " " << j++ << " " << j++;
return 0;
}
```

```
[john@awesome]g++ rtl.cpp -o rtl
[john@awesome]./rtl
0 1 2
[john@awesome]
```

Comment: cool, I didn't know this is compiler dependent. I've always thought this is just how << operator works. +1

Comment: I just tested your code on g++ 4.4.0 and got 2 1 0. This is taking undefined behaviour too far :-)

Comment: No, I'm not - my version string: g++.exe (TDM-1 mingw32) 4.4.0

Comment: Why are you surprised that the order changes. The compiler provides no grantees about the order. I suspect the ordering is more to-do with the underlying ABI being used rather than the compiler version.

Comment: The other thread I've linked to points towards a platform issue, not undefined behavior. It's just not something you can count on if you're writing platform independent code I suppose. This was an interesting little experiment, I love these threads.

Comment: I wasn't really suprised, hence the smiley...

Comment: I just copied the above code but i am getting 
2 1 0

Comment: what compiler and OS are you on though

Comment: I am getting 2 1 0 on g++ 4.3 on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

this is confusing but normal because order of evaluation for this operator is right to left.

Comment: Have U  tried the above thing. If not try it..

Comment: I tried it and I know the result should be 2 1 0 because as I explained the order of evaluate is right to left.