# Acquire/Release semantics

Tags: multithreading, c++11, lock-free, stdatomic

In the answer [StoreStore reordering happens when compiling C++ for x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415565/storestore-reordering-happens-when-compiling-c-for-x86/38415823)
 @Peter Cordes  has written

> For Acquire/Release semantics to give you the ordering you want, the
>   last store has to be the release-store, and the acquire-load has to be
>   the first load. That's why I made y a std::atomic, even though you're
>   setting x to 0 or 1 more like a flag.

I would like to ask some questions to better understand it.

I have read http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics as well. And this article contains: [image]

And it is written that it is ensured that `r2 == 42`. I don't understand why. On my eye it is possible: 
1. Thread2 executed the first line. It is atomic and it is memory_order_acquire so it must be executed before following memory operations.

2. Now, Thread2 executes the second line: `int r2 = A` and `r2` equals to `0`.
3. Then, Thread1 will execute his code.

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complete quote is:

> If we let both threads run and find that r1 == 1, that serves as
>   confirmation that the value of A assigned in Thread 1 was passed
>   successfully to Thread 2. As such, we are guaranteed that r2 == 42.

The aquire-release semantics only guarantee that

- `A = 42` doesn't happen after `Ready = 1` in thread 1
- `r2 = A` doesn't happen before `r1 = Ready` in thread 2

So the value of `r1` has to be checked in thread 2 to be sure that `A` has been written by thread 1. The scenario in the question can indeed happen, but `r1` will be `0` in that case.