# Why are string::append operations behaving strangely?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stl, operator-precedence

look at the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s("1234567890");
    string::iterator i1 = s.begin();
    string::iterator i2 = s.begin();
    string s1, s2;
    s1.append(i1, ++i1);
    s2.append(++i2, s.end());

    cout << s1 << endl;
    cout << s2 << endl;
}
```

what would you expect the output to be?

would you, like me, expect it to be:

```
1
234567890
```

wrong!
it is:

```
234567890
```

i.e. the first string is empty.

seams that prefix increment operator is problematic with iterators. or am I missing something?

Comment: I am not one of the downvoters here, but I suggestion that they arise from your suggestion that you have found a compiler bug. Everyone has a "Have I found a bug in <something really fundamental>?" moment early on (in my case it was libm), and they are all wrong. If you every do discover a bug in something that heavily used it will be after you have a good deal of experience with the tool in question.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is SO full of GCC developers that have felt personally alluded? (I mean developers *of* GCC)

Comment: @Manuel: downvoting because of the way the question was asked.  See http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#id382249 .  Even if this had been a bug, this isn't the right forum for bug reports.  And the title is uselessly generic.  At least there was a good repro recipe.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate, but I don't find the proposed question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c) convincing. The early question is trying to catalog that *actual* behavior of common compilers.

Comment: Well IMO a friendlier reaction would have been for someone with enough rep. to edit the title.

Comment: @ALL, thanks, I do feel stupid for forgetting such a fundamental thing. Well, when you get used to look for the complicated stuff you sometimes overlook the basics. I am not a kind of guy who shouts "bug in the compiler" whenever he has a problem, usually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug.

The order in which the arguments to

```
s1.append(i1, ++i1);
```

are evaluated is not specified by the standard. The compiler is free to use any order it chooses. In this case, it evaluates the second argument (`++i1`) before the first (`i1`) and you specify a null range to copy.

Answer (score 14):

You're missing something: this really has nothing to do with iterators. The order in which arguments to a function are evaluated is unspecified. As such your: `append(i1, ++i1);` would depend on unspecified behavior, regardless of the type of `i1`. Just for example, given something a lot simpler like:

```
void print(int a, int b) { 
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    int a =0;
    print(a, ++a);
    return 0;
}
```

Your output could perfectly reasonably be the "0 1" you seem to expect, but it could also perfectly reasonably be: "1 1". Since this is unspecified, it could change from one version of the compiler to the next, or even with the same compiler when you change flags, or (in theory) could vary depending on the phase of the moon...

Answer (score 8):

C++ implementations are free to evaluate arguments in any order.  In this case, if ++i1 is evaluated first, you will get an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not specify anything about the order in which the function arguments are evaluated, making it implementation dependent. C++ requires that the arguments to a function be completely evaluated (and all side-effects posted) prior to entering the function, but the implementation is free to evaluate the arguments in any order

In your case `i++` got evaluated before making both the parameters same, resulting in an empty string.

More info on this behavior here on [comp.compilers newsgroup](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/95-07-068)