# Doubt in usage of *++p in printf

Tags: c, programming-languages

```
int main(){
    int a[3]={1,10,20};
    int *p=a;
    printf("%d %d " ,*++p,*p);
    return 0;
}
```

The output to the code above is 10 1 on a gcc compiler.

I understand that *++p increments p and dereferences the new value. But since p has been incremented, why does *p return 1 instead of 10?

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour. While it is clear what `*++p` will do (first increment, then dereference), it is not clear whether this or the following `*p` is evaluated first. As such, the output of your program is... kind of random (or more specifically, compiler-specific). It is therefore not possible to "understand" the code.

Comment: @Damon: The behaviour is __not__ undefined. It's unspecified. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c/621548#621548.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unspecified behaviour in what order function argument expressions are evaluated. Some compilers might use left-to-right, some right-to-left, and some might do a different evaluation order depending on the situation for optimalization. So in your case `*p` gets evaluated before `*++p` which results in your "weird output".

Answer (score 2):

The comma between `*++p` and `*p` does *not* denote a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), so this is <strike>undefined</strike>  unspecified behavior.  The compiler is free to 
evaluate `*p` before `*++p`.

Comment: @Damon: The behaviour is __not__ undefined. It's unspecified. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c/621548#621548.

Comment: @jim Lewis: I am the beginer in c.But My Teachers told that in C language the expressions are evaluated from right to left.(i.e) first *p is evaluated then *++p.

Comment: @user618541: You're teacher is wrong. It might be true for one compiler, but not for Standard C.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behaviour, output may various on different compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your arguments are being evaluated in reverse order (last to first) so `*p` is evaluated first and it will return `1`.

As others have pointed out, the standard does not dictate what order the arguments are evaluated and so this behavior may or may not look the same with other compilers.