# Passing uninitialized variables safety

Tags: c++, function, undefined-behavior

I stumbled upon some code today, I simplified it to this :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

bool changeX(int &x)
{
    x = 5;
    return true;
}

void printvals(bool bval, int intval)
{
    cout << bval << " : " << intval;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    printvals(changeX(x), x);
    cin.get();
}
```

Here, `x` is still uninitialized at the time it's passed to the function `printvals` but can I say for sure that x will *always* be initialized before printvals uses it?
I tried to run my simplified code in VS2013 debug-mode which gave me : `Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized.`. However, running it in release-mode ran fine and printed : `1 : 5` as expected.

Does this meant that I can use this approach in production code? Will `x` always be initialized before `printvals` can use it so it doesn't cause UB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilers and argument order of evaluation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> can I say for sure that `x` will always be initialized before `printvals` uses it?

No, the order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified. Since you may read from an uninitialized variable, your code may have *undefined behaviour*. You cannot rely on the side effects of the call to `changeX`.

Answer (score 4):

The order of evaluation of arguments in a function is **unspecified**, so NO, you cannot say that.

See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

or see the standard if you dare read "standardese" :)

PS: even if the order may have been specified, it is always a good idea to avoid code like this, since most of the time other people reading your code will have exactly the same question, and will lose a lot of time digging in. Just prefer clarity over extremely "clever" code.

Comment: Heh, the standardese here is remarkably straightforward, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27947714/2069064). It's actually almost verbatim your first sentence :)

Comment: @Barry, indeed, finally a piece of straightforward english ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could lead to undefined behavior, since order of execution is unspecified (it depends on the compiler).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those places where the C++ standard is extremely easy to understand. From §8.3.6/9 (in N3797, emphasis mine):

> The order of evaluation of function arguments is **unspecified**.

That means you cannot rely on `intval` being evaluated as a copy of `x` *after* `changeX()` is called. Your code is thus undefined behavior.