# Popping a queue in function parameters

Tags: c

I think I might know the answer to this, but I wanted to make sure I fully understand.

I've written a Queue structure in C, as well as operations for use on a Queue struct. I would like to pop the queue, retrieving one element. This element would be the first parameter into my function. I would like to pop the queue again, retrieving the second element. This second element would be my second parameter.

For example:

```
e1 = pop(Q);
e2 = pop(Q);
myfunction(e1, e2);
```

I would like to do this is in a slicker way that doesn't require me to make two throwaway variables.

My assumption would be the following:

```
myfunction(pop(Q), pop(Q))
```

But I'm not 100% sure if this is correct.

Is this correct? Are there slicker ways of accomplishing this?

Comment: *slicker* doesn't mean better. While your assumption is syntactically correct it is prone to multiple runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is undefined, so the second fragment may or may not be equivalent to the first one.

In that case `myfunction(pop(Q), pop(Q))` leads to undefined behaviour.

See also [Compilers and argument order of evaluation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Michael's answer, if this is an often-repeated construct, you can also make a function `myFunctionFromQueue(Q)` which would abstract the boilerplate away.

Additionally, unless you're popping ints or similar, more realistic code would end up looking like:

```
e1 = pop(Q)
e2 = pop(Q)
myFunction(e1, e2)
manage_ownership(e1)
manage_ownership(e2)
```