# printf with arguments functions returning a pointer to char

Tags: c, printf

Hi I tried to setup a code like

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct _data;
typedef struct _data data;
typedef struct _data {
    double x;
    double y;
} data;

const char* data_tostring(data* a) {
    static char buffer[255];
    sprintf(buffer, "%f %f", a->x, a->y);
    return buffer;
}

int main(){
    data a;
    data b;
    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;
    b.x = 1;
    b.y = 1;
    printf("%s %s \n", data_tostring(&a), data_tostring(&b));
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output was 0 0 1 1, but actually I get 0 0 0 0. Did I make a mistake with the `static` keyword and the returning value in `data_tostring()`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Since `buffer` is `static`, both calls to `data_tostring(...)` are writing to the same buffer. Furthermore, the order of evaluation of function parameters in unspecified, so there's no guarantee that `data_tostring(&a)` gets evaluated before `data_tostring(&b)`.

One possible way of fixing this is by passing `buffer` as an argument to `data_tostring`:

```
void data_tostring(char* buffer, data* a) {
    sprintf(buffer, "%f %f", a->x, a->y);
}
```

And then use multiple buffers in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    data a;
    data b;
    char a_buf[255];
    char b_buf[255];

    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;
    b.x = 1;
    b.y = 1;

    // Fill buffers
    data_tostring(a_buf, &a);
    data_tostring(b_buf, &b);

    printf("%s %s \n", a_buf, b_buf);
    return 0;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/agjdBKaM3CxRrvuR)

---

If you really want to use the `static buffer`, you can call `printf` twice:

```
int main()
{
    data a;
    data b;
    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;
    b.x = 1;
    b.y = 1;
    printf("%s", data_tostring(&a));
    printf(" %s \n", data_tostring(&b));
    return 0;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xKoqPdxGlSq4x4LI)

Comment: unfortunately, your solution is exactly what I would like to avoid :)

Comment: @Fabio: why? If you want to use the same buffer you need two separate calls to `printf`.

Comment: @Fabio: edited my answer with an alternative solution using the `static buffer`.

Comment: your second post is my actual implementation. But thanks

Comment: @Fabio: it's not. Read the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: sorry I mispelled, I would say is "my actual" (on my computer right now) implementation to solve the problem I posted.

Answer (score 1):

- The problem is because in C language, **the arguments in a function are evaluated from `right to left`**.
- So, first `data_tostring(&b)` is evaluated and the pointer points to the buffer char array.
- Next, the `data_tostring(&a)` is evaluated and this time, the char values present already are overwritten by `sprintf(buffer, "%f %f", a->x, a->y);`.
- So, after the two argument evaluations, the two function evaluations points to buffer char array which has the values of `struct a`. That's the reason you got 0 0 0 0.

Alternative solution:

> Use two printf() statements and print the strings seperately or use two char buffers for each of the structs(Not recommended).

Reference: [Compilers and argument order of evaluation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c)

Hope this helps.