# Do the Requirements Placed on Function Arguments Also Apply to Initializer Lists?

Tags: c++, arguments, language-lawyer, initializer-list, sequencing

So I've read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/598150/2642059 that this is illegal:

```
foo(i++, i++);
```

But I believe that's because there is not a forced sequence, which I understand is the case for Initializer Lists. So is this legal code?

```
const int foo[] = { i++, i++ };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the order of the evaluation of initializer-clauses is guaranteed in braced-init-list.

From the standard, [§11.6.4/4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#4):

(emphasis mine)

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions,
>   are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value
>   computation and side effect associated with a given initializer-clause
>   **is sequenced before** every value computation and side effect associated
>   with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated
>   list of the initializer-list. [ Note: This evaluation ordering holds
>   regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it
>   applies when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as
>   arguments of a constructor call, even though ordinarily there are no
>   sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. — end note ]

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Notes):

> Every initializer clause is [sequenced
>   before](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) any
>   initializer clause that follows it in the braced-init-list. This is in
>   contrast with the arguments of a [function call
>   expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator),
>   which are
>   [unsequenced](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Example for the note of the standard,

```
struct A { A(int, int) {} };
...
int i = 0;
A a1(i++, i++); // used as the arguments of the constructor; unsequenced
A a2{i++, i++}; // used as the arguments of the constructor; sequenced, within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the `note` section i.e. the constructor call part.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Added to the answer.