# += Operator while passing as argument

Tags: c++, evaluation

I have following snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void test(int arg_1, int arg_2, int arg_3, int arg_4)
{
    std::cout << arg_1 << ", " << arg_2 << ", " << arg_3 << ", " << arg_4 << std::endl;
}
```

I ran following scenarios but i am unable to understand them. Please explain them.

**Case-1:**

```cpp
int i;
i = 200;
test(i, i, i, i);
```

Case-1 - Output:

```
200, 200, 200, 200
```

**Case-2:**

```cpp
int i;
i = 200;
test(i++, i++, i++, i++);
```

Case-2 - Output:

```
203, 202, 201, 200
```

**Case-3:**

```cpp
int i;
i = 200;
test(i++, i+=10, i++, i++);
```

Case-3 - Output:

```
212, 213, 201, 200
```

**Case-4:**

```cpp
int i;
i = 200;
test(i++, i++, i+=10, i++);
```

Case-4 - Output:

```
212, 211, 213, 200
```

**Case-5:**

```cpp
int i;
i = 200;
test(i++, i++, i++, i+=10);
```

Case-5 - Output:

```
212, 211, 210, 213
```

**Case-6:**

```cpp
int i;
i = 200;
test(i++, i+=10, i++, i+=1);
```

Case-6 - Output:

```
212, 213, 201, 213
```

Case-1 is just for reference; while Case-2 is easy to understand. But from Case-3 to Case-6; i have no idea what is going on. Kindly explain such behavior.

Also; are there any official docs/reference for such behavior?

Comment: Except case 1, all your cases leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, but I suspect almost all of your sample cases (save for #1) are in undefined behavior territory.

Comment: The official doc is the C++ standard, which says "The order of argument evaluation is undefined". This changes however in C++17. I don't have standard nearby, but hopefully somebody else can provide a proper answer

Comment: As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598148/is-it-legal-to-use-the-increment-operator-in-a-c-function-call this is `undefined behaviour`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Ok. I hope someone will explain the correct behavior has per C++17(if it is there). To me; case3 to 5 are following some order; but for case-6, i am clueless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17

Answer (score 0):

the short answer for you is:

> The order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of evaluation of function arguments is ***unspecified***

refer to this:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order