# In C++11, how to iterate in reverse for standard containers using "enhanced for loop"?

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11, foreach, reverse-iterator

Below is an [example](http://ideone.com/JKHahH) with `std::deque` for forward looping, using "enhanced for loop":

```
  int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  std::deque<int> dq(a, a+6);    
  for(auto i : dq) 
    std::cout << i << ", ";
```

What is the correct syntax (if possible) of "enhanced for loop" to iterate in reverse for a given STL container?

Comment: @Yuushi, Thanks, I too will vote for close (not deleting to let this question be there for another Google search for future visitora). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14468490/514235) seems to be without using Boost.