# When using the range based for-loop in c++, how do I tell it which iterator to use

Tags: c++

I'm wondering which iterator the range based for loop uses for classes like std::map; I'm assuming by default it uses std::map::iterator instead of say std::map::reverse_iterator. Is this correct, and is there a way that I can tell it to instantiate the iterator that I prefer, or do I just need to use a traditional for loop at that point?

for ( const auto & keyValue : myMap ) <---- Does this use the std::map::iterator, can I use std::map::reverse_iterator

Comment: There's some proposal for C++14 I think for allow iterator adaptor like you are asking but in C++11 the forward iterator (normal) is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> — if _RangeT is a class type, the unqualified-ids begin and end are
>   looked up in the scope of class _RangeT as if by class member access
>   lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one
>   declaration, beginexpr and end-expr are __range.begin() and
>   __range.end(), respectively;

So in your case member functions `begin()` and `end()` of class `std::map` are called.

I suggested to the C+= Standard Committee to introduce something as

```
for ( auto x : reverse Container )
```

and till now I do not know the result of my suggesting though as far as I know the Committee is investigating the question.

As for your case then you can use some wrapper for an original standard container that will define member functions begin and end and will use reverse iterators of the container.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8544956/648689), using `boost::adaptors::reverse()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to reverse iterate as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542591/c11-reverse-range-based-for-loop), but it uses boost library.

The `for ( const auto & keyValue : myMap )` uses a normal `std::map::iterator` though.

Another way to reverse iterate would be:

```
for (std::map::reverse_iterator iterator mymap.rbegin(); iterator != mymap.rend(); ++iterator)
```

Which is accepted by c++98 (not only c++11).

Comment: "default C++" you mean C++98?  The C++ programming language has a history going back to 1979.

Comment: I don't know if it's from 98 or 03. I just meant that everything (that I now of) nowadays can run it with `::reverse_iterator`, but ROS, for example, doesn't run, by default, c++11. I'll correct it. Thanks for pointing that out. Is it from 98 or 03? Do you know?

Comment: For what it's worth, `++iterator` is marginally more efficient than `iterator++`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But why is it more efficient?

Comment: Just because the postfix notation needs to copy the iterator, increment the original, and then return the copy. Many (most?) iterators are so lightweight that this doesn't matter, but some are not.

Comment: @t.pimentel: The STL was added to C++ in 1994, the next release of the standard was '98.  '03 didn't change much to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In short, rule for range-based `for` is like this: it calls `myMap.begin()` and `myMap.end()` if they exist. Otherwise it calls `begin(myMap)` and `end(myMap)`. So yes, in case of `std::map` it uses `std::map::iterator`.

If you want to iterate backwards you can write an adaptor yourself or use [`boost::adaptors::reverse`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html).

See also this: [C++11 reverse range-based for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8542591/3959454)

Update: here are full rules for range-based `for` (`§6.5.4`), for reference:

> - if `_RangeT` is an array type, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, where `__bound` is the array bound. If `_RangeT` is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
> - if `_RangeT` is a class type, the unqualified-ids begin and end are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, `beginexpr` and `end-expr` are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`, respectively;
> - otherwise, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where begin and end are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace std is an associated namespace.

Comment: Technically it uses `begin(myMap)` which is slightly different.

Comment: @MooingDuck `.begin()` and `.end()` take precedence, see my update

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that!  I thought it only used `begin`.  Huh.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) uses forward iteration. If you want to iterate backwards, then you need to do it yourself.