# Printing a list giving error that says Iterator is not decrementable

Tags: c++, list, class

I am trying to create a member function that is supposed to replicate a stack by using a list. So I have to print the elements of the list in reverse order. 
I have a private list declared in my header file as:

```
class miniStackLT {
private:
    list<T> content;
```

I have the following code for that function:

```
template <typename T>
void miniStackLT<T>::PrintStack(){
    list<T>::iterator iter;
    iter = content.end();
    iter--;
    while (iter != content.end()) {
    cout << *iter << " | ";
    iter--;
    }
}
```

When I run the program I check the size of the so list and it tells me the correct number but when I print it, it prints the correct elements then I get an error that says the list iterator is not decrementable.

What is causing this error? I have tried messing around with the starting and ending points of the loop and the iterator, but I keep getting the error.

Edit: I have also used

```
template <typename T>
void miniStackLT<T>::PrintStack(){
    list<T>::iterator rit;
    for (auto rit = content.rbegin(); rit != content.rend(); ++rit){
        cout << *iter << " | ";
    }
}
```

But I still get the error.

Comment: `for (auto i = list.rbegin(); i != list.rend(); ++i)` Done in reverse...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues with your code.  First `while (iter != content.end())` will always be true since you are walking backwards away from `content.end()`.  Second, even if you change it to `while (iter != content.begin())` you will miss the first iterator in the list

The way to walk a list backwards is to use a reverse iterator.  `std::list` has `rbegin()` and `rend()` which give you begin and end iterators but they traverse the list backwards so `rbegin()` gives you the last element in the list.  to walk the list you would just use something like

```
for (auto rit = content.rbegin(); rit != content.rend(); ++rit)
```

You could also one up that and use a ranged based for loop.  Using the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28139075/4342498) by [Prikso NAI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3970469/prikso-nai) you would be able to have

```
for (const auto& e : reverse(content))
    std::cout << e << " | ";
```

Comment: Still getting the same error when I try this method

Comment: @ZackSloan You don't change the iterator before you do `for (auto rit = content.rbegin(); rit != content.rend(); ++rit)` do you?

Comment: No, I just declare it as `list<T>::iterator rit;`

Comment: @ZackSloan Can you add the updated code to your question?

Comment: @ZackSloan I saw you edit and I can't see why it would not work.  You would need to provide a full [mcve] to figure it out.

Comment: Figured it out, was using `cout << *iter << " | ";` instead of `cout << *rit << " | ";`

Comment: @ZackSloan Oh yeah.  I missed that as well.  Glad you got it

Answer (score 0):

At some point you reach `content.begin()`. After that, it is not decrementable.

Changing your condition to `while (iter != content.begin())` should fix this.

But you should consider using `rbegin()` and `rend()` and a reverse iterator.