# Iterating ranged-based for loop from end to begin

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, c++14, ranged-loops

Reverse iteration from last item to first item can be done like this:

```cpp
for (int i = myContainer.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    // Do
}
```

How can I reverse a ranged-based for loop:

```cpp
for (auto i : myContainer) {
    // Do
}
```

Comment: This might help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542591/c11-reverse-range-based-for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

```
std::reverse(std::begin(myContainer), std::end(myContainer));
for (auto i : myContainer) {
    // Do
}
```

This will add O(n) iterator swaps

Comment: Thanks. Is using `std::reverse` computationally more expensive than the traditional `for (int i = myContainer.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)` method?

Comment: Yes, O(n) iterator swaps are added

Comment: Right. I think I might stick to the traditional `for (int i = myContainer.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)` to avoid the added expense of `std::reverse`.

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad solution. No one would modify the whole container just to iterate it backwards.

Comment: @paceholder This is a correct answer to the question. You are free to provide a better answer.

Comment: @ThomasSablik a better answer is provided [at the top-most link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542591/c11-reverse-range-based-for-loop). The question was how to perform a reversed iteration, not how to reverse the whole container and do a forward loop. I agree that your code could print-out elements in a desired order but it could be a performance kill. I had to warn anyone reading the answers that this solution is a bad one. Sorry, once again, nothing personal.

Comment: @paceholder Adding boost to some projects can be an overkill. I'm currently working in a project where it's not possible to include boost. That's the reason why different solutions exist. In many cases where the loop has complexity O(n log n) or worse adding O(n) isn't that bad.

Comment: @ThomasSablik O-notation is not the same as elapsed real time. Reversing a billion of "large" elements is very expensive. If boost is not allowed, one should stick to the classical reversed loop with indices or write a small wrapper-class implementing `begin()` as `rbegin()` and `end()` as `rend()`.

Comment: @paceholder classical reversed loop was posted in the question. OP knows about that. The question is if there is a way to use a range based loop. My answer contains a solution and the extra costs.

Comment: @ThomasSablik your solution does not work with a const container.