# iterator for the last element of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I need to get an iterator to the last element in a `std::vector`.

As known `end()` method returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container. Can I implement what I need by using `end() - 1`?

As far as I understand I can't use `back()` method, since it returns a reference.

Comment: See also [Iterating C++ vector from the end to the begin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3610933/96780).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest is probably `your_vec.rbegin()`.

Comment: the iterators' type don't match.

Comment: @athos: Doesn't match...what? He simply asked for an iterator to the last element, and `rbegin()` provides that. If you want some non-reverse iterator to the last element, well, perhaps you should ask a question about that; it's clearly a different question than the OP asked here though.

Answer (score 11):

Given that you know/have checked that the vector is not empty and C++11 is an option, you can use [std::prev](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
auto it = std::prev( your_vector.end() ); // or .cend() if a const_iterator is OK
```

Also note that using `rbegin()` returns a reverse iterator, which is different from a normal iterator.

Comment: Very helpful - I just discovered the issue with rbegin() returning a reverse iterator, when I tried assigning the result to a forward iterator.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thats the [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) iterator. For example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3};

    for(auto& it = v.rbegin() ; it != v.rend() ; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
}
```

The output is:

> 3 2 1 0

Comment: LOL I was reading the documentation I linked about [`std::rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and I just noticed that feature is ***since C++14***.

Comment: I always use `std::begin()`, so using `std::rbegin()` was a natural reflex action, even if it doesn't exist yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reverse_iterators`. `vec.rbegin()` will give you a `reverse_iterator` pointing at the last element in the vector. More about it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the iterator for?  If it is for iterating from
back to front, you can use the reverse iterators (`rbegin`,
`rend`).  If it is a function which expects an iterator (for
example, because you want it to iterate through all but the last
element), then you can use `end() - 1` on a vector.  This will
only work on random access iterators, however; for other types,
you will need `std::prev` (if you've got C++11) or the
equivalent from your toolkit (pre C++11):

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
BidirectionalIterator
prev( BidirectionalIterator it )
{
    -- it;
    return it;
}
```

(If you don't have it already, and aren't using C++11, add it to
your toolkit.)