# How is end() implemented in STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl

So when we need to traverse a container from start to end we write something like

`for (i = v->begin(); i != v->end(); i++)`

assuming `i` is an iterator for container `v`.

My question is "what guarantees that end will always point to one past the last element in container?" How does STL ensures this behavior and is there any chance that this case is not true?

Comment: The STL does not guarantee this behavior. The STL **implements** this behavior based on the requirements defined by the standard. The standard says this is how it is supposed to work the developer that implements the STL is then supposed to make the STL work correctly.

Comment: That's not best practice.  Prefer the pre-increment operator ++i rather than i++ when you are not storing the value.  For many types it is faster.

Comment: @Jive Dadson: that's not my main concern --> recomputing `v->end()` at each turn of the loop certainly is less efficient... `for (auto it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)` is the canonical form, though in C++0x one might as well use `for (auto val : v)` or `std::foreach` and a lambda function.

Answer (score 25):

STL ensures this behavior by always storing stuff like this:

[image: vector]

In the end (pun), it doesn't matter what `end()` ***is***, as long as it's always `end()` (and, obviously, can't be confused with any other node).

Comment: Mate, you get +1 just for the funky graphics :-)

Comment: Doesn't the quote below from the C++ standard invalidate this answer? especially the graphic.

Answer (score 3):

The stl specification guarantees that end will be one past the end **[See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/end/)**. That will always be the case. Exactly how it does this can depend on the implementation (sometimes the values is just set to null for example), but rest assured your loop will be OK as long as v is a valid pointer.

Answer (score 3):

C++03 Section `23.1/7` says

> begin() returns  an  iterator  referring  to  the  first  element  in  the  container.
>
> end() returns  an  iterator which is the **past-the-end** value for the container.
>
> If the container is empty, then `begin() == end()`;

Comment: Is this the reason slist  isn't officialy STL ? the end() of slist is 0

Answer (score 2):

"end will always point to one past the last element in container" means that if you increment iterator that points to the last element it will be equal to the result of `end()`. Implementation can be different. In Visual C++ `std::vector::end()` returns implementation specific iterator that holds zero pointer.

Comment: I strongly doubt it, as `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a random-access iterator. If `std::vector<T>::end()` returned `(T*)0`, `end()-begin()` would be illegal, yet it needs to return `std::vector::size()`

Comment: To be more correct: `end` returns implementation specific iterator that holds zero pointer.

Comment: The part of *holding zero pointer* is, well, unneeded and imprecise. In gcc vector implementation, `vector<>::end()` is defined as `vector<>::begin()+vector<>::size()`, and is actually stored in the `vector<>` object (GCC vector is implemented by means of three pointers: *begin*, *end* and *end_of_capacity*, where `begin==end` if the vector is empty, `begin+size()==end` at all times and `end==end_of_capacity` if `size()==capacity()`. There are no *zero pointer* anywhere to be seen.

Comment: @David Rodríguez, That was in "Implementation can be different." part of my answer. "zero pointer" is related to the Visual C++ implementation, not to gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about all STL containers... not a word of mention of vector specifically where end() *might* be implemented as you obviously intuitively expect.  What's one past the end in a std::map<>?  The "end is one past the last used node" thing is just a logical concept, expressing that you can safely increment from that last-used node, differentiate/equate it from/to the abstract concept of "end", and do some node arithmetic where end is considered to be one further along than the last-used node.  Don't take it too literally.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the previous posters have stated `end()` is one past the end element.  If you need to access the last element via iterators use `iter = container.end() - 1;`  Otherwise, in the case of vectors, `variable = someVector.back();`  Assuming that variable is of the data type `someVector` contains.

In regard to what guarantees that it points to the end, the container itself handles that internally.  You just have to treat it like a blackbox like any other object and trust it does it correctly.

Whenever the container is resized, it will track where the end is and will be up to date before you access `end()` again.  Depending on the container however, if you have an iterator and alter it in some ways, it can invalidate the iterator and break your iteration process.