# Can you change a std::list while iterating through it?

Tags: c++, std

In the following functions, it it entirely possible for the IObserver's `Process()` function to try to remove itself from the notify list, using the `this` pointer's `DeleteObserver()`.

This causes hell with the iterators (not surprisingly!), is there a way round this? Or should I be taking a closer look at my design?

```
void cButtonManager::DeleteObserver(IObserver *observer)
{
    list<IObserver*>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = m_ObserverList.begin(); iter != m_ObserverList.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (*iter == observer)
        {
            // Found the specified observer in the list, delete it
            m_ObserverList.erase(iter);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void cButtonManager::NotifyObservers(void)
{
    list<IObserver*>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = m_ObserverList.begin(); iter != m_ObserverList.end(); ++iter)
    {
        (*iter)->Process(this);
    }
}
```

For example, imagine that the list is a collection of people that subscribe to a magazine and the `Process()` function is the delivery of a new magazine issue; if the magazines latest issue is awful the subscriber may wish to un-subscribe as a direct result of that issue.

Comment: This code is legal as far as I see. The only problem you may have is if you have several threads accessing the list, or if you receive a `DeleteObserver` call while you're in the middle of another loop through the list.

Comment: @GWW: The `(iter*)->Process()` function returns and the program crashes, because iter now points to nothing at all, so the `++iter` operation fails. @Diego: Yup, you got it, the deletion is occurring within the process-loop.

Comment: @Siyfion, but this means that `Process` is indirectly calling `DeleteObserer`. If that happens, yes, this code is problematic.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it ?

Comment: @ltjax, nope, because iterator in place where he calls `erase()` is not the same iterator, that makes the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Some people in comments corrected me, so I will change this answer. But don't upvote, as it's the commenters' solution, not mine.

```
(*iter++)->Process();
```

Comment: You could use the iterator returned by `erase` and return that from `Process`, assigning it to `iter`.

Comment: Yes, but that would require changes in `Process()`; here, only the code that uses it is required to be changed. Do you think that `Process()` is always called in loop? I don't think so, so returning an iterator from it would result in compiler warnings. And it is obviously not always used with iterators.

Comment: You can also write `(*iter++)->Process();`. It's a bit tricksy, but the sequence point at the start of the function call to `Process` guarantees that the side effect of incrementing `iter` occurs before the old value of `iter` can be invalidated by whatever `Process` does.

Comment: `list::iterator` has no `operator+()`.

Comment: Griwes: I don't know what `Process` does, nor when and how it is used in the rest of the OP's code. It was only a suggestion of how C++ can help you avoid an extra line of code.

Comment: @SteveJessop, hmm, I didn't think about that. But a question, is it a standard-defined or ID (probably the first one, but I would say same thing about some ID features of C++...)?

Comment: @rubenvb, read what I wrote once again. And what if there was no `erase()` called, where should the `Process` get the iterator from?

Comment: @Griwes: it's guaranteed by the standard, although it takes some close reading to convince yourself of it. Basically the operand of `operator->` is evaluated before the operator is, and hence before the call to `Process`. The sequence point on the function call forces the side-effects to be completed too.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy for you to get upvotes for this: I suggested the change because (a) it's shorter than your code, and (b) you were going to have to change your code anyway to get rid of the `iter+1` :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, I'm just trying to be honest :P

Comment: @Griwe, the upvotes are not there for you, they're for the readers. :)

Comment: @SteveJessop very nice solution there it's clean, elegant and works! Some may say that it's slightly tricksy, but it's a lot better than the alternative.

Comment: Even better, I've realised it's less tricksy than I thought. In the case of `std::list`, the iterator must be a user-defined type (well library-defined, but the effect is the same). It can't just be a pointer like `vector` can, or like a generic iterator could be. So, it has an `operator++` function, and hence the side-effects of `iter++` are guaranteed to have completed when `operator++` returns, which is even earlier than I said above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are not using `list::remove` here. That seems like a perfect match to me.

For the problem in `NotifyObserver` I would not let `Process` do the removing itself but rather let it signal that it wants itself to be removed from the list of observer. Plainly: return a bool from `Process` to signal and then call `list::erase` on it. Assign the return value of `erase` to the current `iter`.

Comment: FWIW, `list::remove` removes all elements matching a value, whereas the code shown in `DeleteObserver` only removes one. I strongly suspect that there can only *be* one match, so the difference is only one of performance, not effect. I don't think it helps with actual question, though, which is about the code in `NotifyObservers`, not the code in `DeleteObserver` (which `Process` is permitted to call, but presumably `Process` can do other worthwhile things too).

Comment: @SteveJessop The current behaviour rather looks like a bug to me than intentional, but that is up to the OP. I tried to provide a simple solution for the second function.

Comment: @pmr Indeed there can only be one match in the list to an Observer, the `AddObserver()` function (not shown) checks for uniqueness. The reason why I am using erase is because I was wondering if I would need the returned iterator (which `remove()` doesn't provide).

Also, the other problem is that Process *could* remove itself from the list, but it's also entirely possible that `DeleteObserver()` is called elsewhere too (in the same thread however).