# How to properly point back to std::list after erasing en element (double for loop)?

Tags: c++, iterator, unhandled-exception, erase, stdlist

I want to erase an element from the `std::list` and then point back to this list but when I do it this way

```
for(std::list<CvRect>::iterator it = listOfCvRects.begin(); it != listOfCvRects.end(); it++)
{
    for(std::list<CvRect>::iterator jt = listOfCvRects.begin();  jt != listOfCvRects.end(); jt++)
    {
        if( it == jt )
        { continue;}

        if( (jt->x) > (it->x) //.. more conditions...)
        {
            jt = listOfCvRects.erase(jt);
            //OR 
            //listOfCvRects.erase(jt++);
        }
    }

}
```

I got and unhandled exception : `iterator is unincrementable`

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/596162/624900)

Comment: If the condition is symmetric, you could start the inner loop at `jt = it;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that in some cases (those where you delete an element), you are double incrementing the iterator. Your for loop looks like this:

```
for(std::list<T>::iterator jt = l.begin();  jt != l.end(); jt++) {
    ....
}
```

But inside of it you are doing something like this:

```
jt = l.erase(jt);
```

So, if the case happens that you do the erase, you erase it and at the same time, set the iterator to the next element... But, you also increment it with the `jt++`!

The simple approach to fixing this is re-write the for loop slightly to fit this form factor:

```
for(std::list<T>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ) { // notice no increment!
    // ...
    if(cond) {
        it = l.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

so you are doing one or the other increments, but never both.

Comment: So what can I do to avoid it ?

Comment: @Patryk: see update, I was trying to get the basics in there quick while I was typing the full answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

Erasing an element from a list invalidates iterators that point at that element, but not other iterators.  So you need to do the increment before the erase:

```
for(std::list<CvRect>::iterator it = listOfCvRects.begin(); it != listOfCvRects.end(); it++) {
    std::list<CvRect>::iterator jt = listOfCvRects.begin();
    while (jt != listOfCvRects.end()) {
        if( it == jt) continue;
        if( (jt->x) > (it->x) //.. more conditions...) {
            listOfCvRects.erase(jt++);
        } else {
            jt++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `erase` returns an iterator to the next element (or `end()`).