# Having an issue with c++ stl lists

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have the following function.

```
void BulletFactory::update(Uint32 ticks) {
  std::list<Sprite*>::iterator it = activeBullets.begin();
  while (it != activeBullets.end()) {
    (*it)->update(ticks);
    if(!((*it)->inView())) {
      activeBullets.remove(*it);
      Sprite* temp = *it;
      it++;
      inactiveBullets.push_back(temp);
    } else {
      it++;
    }
  }
}
```

when the condition `!((*it)->inView())` is being `true` there is a segmentation fault. I am not able to see the problem.

edit: forgot to mention that activeBullets and inactiveBullets are two lists.

Comment: Removing from a list like this isn't safe, you need to get the result of remove as your new iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 activeBullets.remove(*it);
 Sprite* temp = *it; //<--- problem
 it++; //<-- problem
```

should be:

```
  Sprite* temp = *it;
  it = activeBullets.erase(it); //use erase
  //it++; don't increment it
```

Comment: it works, but can you explain me the problem in more detail. what is the difference between remove and erase.

Comment: @user1198065: There are lots of topics on this site. You can search them. For example, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it

Answer (score 1):

You must not modify the element that the iterator is pointing to, because it invalidates the iterator. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it) for solutions.