# a small issue with std::vector and changing the collection while looping through it

Tags: c++, stdvector

This loop changes the iterators while running:

```
std::vector<int> c;
c.push_back(1);
c.push_back(2);

std::vector<int>::iterator iter    = c.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator endIter = c.end();

while( iter != endIter )
{
    std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;
    iter = c.erase(iter);
}
```

It does not work because:

> Iterators and references to the erased elements and to the elements between them and the end of the container are invalidated. Past-the-end iterator is also invalidated

How can I rewrite this (without using `std::list`, and using the `while` loop) ?

By the way, I know that `auto` has been implemented since C++11. Why would it be beneficial to use it ?

Comment: You could do it without iterators, or do it in two steps: first print them all out, then erase the whole list. It depends what you're trying to do and a demo like this isn't really trying to do anything. (Auto is completely orthogonal to this: ask about that in another question.)

Comment: This is a dummy example. But what I really store in the vector are `CvPoint2D32f*`. And in the `while` loop, I add the info from these `CvPoint2D32f*` to fill a `CV_MAT_ELEM`. But at every iteration I want to delete the erase the element since I don't need it anymore.

Comment: "since I don't need it any more" is a poor reason to turn your code inside out. Go through the whole vector and then when you're done, clear it since you don't need it any more. Simple and readable. On the matter of caching end() - in general, don't help the compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you remove elements from a std::list while iterating through it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply do not cache the end iterator that will be invalidated:

```
while( iter != c.end() )
{
    std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;
    iter = c.erase(iter);
}
```

or clear the vector after printing:

```
for(const auto& i : c) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
c.clear();
```

Comment: Another good idiom for consuming a `vector` in a multi-threaded context is to acquire the lock and then `swap(accumulated_vector, local_vector)` and then drop the lock.  Then process the captured values in `local_vector` and discard it.

Answer (score 12):

Erasing an element changes `end()`. Change the loop:

```
while( iter != c.end())
```

Answer (score 7):

Either

- Rewrite it as

  ```
  while( iter != c.end() )
  {
      std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;
      iter = c.erase(iter);
  }
  ```

  and the code will no longer rely on any potentially invalidated iterators,

or

- "Refresh" any potentially invalidated iterators after each invalidating operation

  ```
  while( iter != endIter )
  {
      std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;
      iter = c.erase(iter);
      endIter = c.end();
  }
  ```

These are the two generic approaches typically used in cases like that.

Answer (score 3):

A more idiomatic way of doing this...

```
while(c.begin() != c.end()) c.erase(c.begin());
```

Though this is very slow, as a vectors underlying implementation uses a contiguous array(with extra space on the end).  So repeatedly erasing the begin element is very ineficient, as every element ends up getting copied one space in the array earlier, n - index times!  You can jurastically increase performance by doing this:

```
while(c.begin() != c.end()) c.pop_back();
```