# Delete matching characters

Tags: c++

Having some trouble with some code. The rule is that if two characters must match, the duplicated letter must be deleted. So for example "Usually" would be changed to "Usualy".

The code does work however it doesn't do what was mentioned above.

I will post the code below and comment put a comment above the problem spot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void printList(const list<char> &myList);
void fillList(list<char> &myList);
void change(list <char> &myList);

void printList(const list<char> &myList)
{
    list<char>::const_iterator itr;
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    {
        cout <<*itr;
    }
    cout << '\n' << endl;
}

void fillList(list<char> &myList)
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    string print;
    while(file >> print)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=print.length(); i++)
        {
            myList.push_back(print[i]);
        }
        myList.push_back(' ');
    }
}

void change(list <char> &myList)
{
    list<char>::iterator itr;

    //rules are as follows

    //change w with v
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    {
        if (*itr == 'w')
        {
            *itr = 'v';
        }
    }

    // double letter become single letter here
    //PROBLEM IS HERE!
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    {
        std::list<char>::iterator itr2 = itr;
        if(*(++itr2) == *itr)
        {
            myList.remove(*itr);
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    list<char> myList;
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    const string print;
    fillList(myList);
    printList(myList);
    change(myList);
    printList(myList);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What trouble? What problem? Any particular error? Is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it relevant?

Comment: I will update the description

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are modifying a list while traversing it using the same iterator:

```
for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
{
    std::list<char>::iterator itr2 = itr;
    if(*(++itr2) == *itr)
    {
        myList.remove(*itr);
    }
}
```

You want to do something more like this:

```
for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); )
{
    std::list<char>::iterator before = itr++;
    if(*itr != myList.end() && *before == *itr)
    {
        myList.erase(before);
    }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion doesn't compile. I am getting an error, saying no match for operator=

Comment: `list::erase()` returns an iterator to the next item following the one being removed.

Comment: @TheByteMonster: don't deference the `iterator` when comparing it to `end()`.

Answer (score -1):

The second loop in `change()` is modifying the `list` while iterating through it, but you are not updating your loop `iterator` to account for that.  `list::erase()` returns an `iterator` to the next item in the list after the specified item is removed.

You are also not taking into account that `++itr2` could produce the `end()` iterator, which is not safe to dereference.

Try this instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

void change(std::list<char> &myList)
{
    //rules are as follows

    //change w with v
    std::replace(myList.begin(), myList.begin(), 'w', 'v');

    // double letter become single letter here
    list<char>::iterator itr = myList.begin();
    while (itr != myList.end())
    {
        std::list<char>::iterator itr2 = itr++;
        if ((itr != myList.end()) && (*itr2 == *itr))
        {
            myList.erase(itr2);
            // or: itr = myList.erase(itr);
        }
    }
}
```

A simpler solution is to use [`std::unique()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) instead (if you don't mind allowing 3+ duplicates to be removed at a time):

> Removes all consecutive duplicate elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

```
#include <algorithm>

void change(std::list<char> &myList)
{
    //rules are as follows

    //change w with v
    std::replace(myList.begin(), myList.begin(), 'w', 'v');

    // multiple letter become single letter here
    std::list<char>::iterator itr = std::unique(myList.begin(), myList.end());
    myList.erase(itr, myList.end()); 
}
```