# Bug when erasing std::list items

Tags: c++

Here I created a list which is a copy of another list. This list is called copied. I am trying to create a shuffled list of the numbers in copied. The user enters the size of the initial list (how many cards they want), and a list is created and that list is used here to be shuffled. But for some reason when the user enters more that 20, I get this error:

```
output(41432,0x7fff7389e000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff55638490: 
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is the section of my code. When I remove the while (!copied.empty()) loop, it works fine, as in it puts the "it" value in position "r" from the initial list into the new list. But I need for it to do it for each "r".

```
    list<size_t> copied;
    copied.insert(copied.end(), cards.begin(), cards.end());
    int r = rand()%(((copied.size()+1) - 0) + 1) + 0;

    list<size_t>::const_iterator it = copied.begin();

    while(!copied.empty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            it++;}
        shuffle.push_back(*it);
        copied.erase(it);}
```

Comment: `it` is defined as a `list<size_t>::const_iterator`, while the `std::list` `erase()` method is only defined for `iterator`. `iterator` and `const_iterator` are distinct types. Also, see this question on removing elements from a list while iterating: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it

Comment: If there's only one value in `copied`, `copied.size()` is 1, so (1+1-0+1) is 3, so r can be any value between 0 and 2, so `copied.begin()` can be incremented anywhere between 0 and 2 times. Good luck incrementing `copied.begin()` even one time, attempting to dereference it, and expecting a meaningful result. Your problem is basic math, and needing a better grasp on how iterators, and 0-based array/container indexing works.

Comment: Also, `erase` invalidates the iterator. You can't just then *increment* it and expect to be back in the remainder of the list.

Comment: "Each 'r'"? `r` doesn't change during your `while` loop.

Comment: thank you Beta & Polb. I fixed it

Comment: This is **not** a compilation error. It is a runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `copied.erase(it)` invalidates the iterator `it`, so any subsequent use of it is undefined behavior.  You can instead use

```
it = copied.erase(it);
if (it == copied.end()) it = copied.begin();
```

since `erase` returns a valid iterator to the next element after the one being erased.  You also need to worry about the `it++` in the `for` loop running off the end of the list, so that should probably be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    if (++it == copied.end())
        it = copied.begin(); }
```

Comment: No, this answer is wrong. Carefully review the shown code. It only looks this way because of the garbled indentation in the shown code. The `erase();` only terminates the outer loop, all the iterator incrementing occurs before the `erase()`, and its the increments per se that's the problem, running off the end of the container. This is just a bad question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I can only go by whats in the posted code -- it is syntactically correct if semantically nonsense.  `erase` does not terminate a loop -- the loop continues after the erase, looping again.

Comment: And it is exactly the posted code. The posted code never increments the invalidated iterator. The incrementing itself invalidated the iterator, prior to the `erase()`. The `erase();` ends the ***outer*** while loop. Count the braces.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik:  After the `erase`, it evaluates the `while` condition again, which will still be true, so it runs the loop a second time, running the inner `for` loop again, and incrementing the iterator again.

Comment: Eh, that's right. Except that the initial incrementing, on the first iteration, can invalidate the iterator right off the bat, because of the broken calculation of the randomly-generated initial increment. A double-whammy.