# Remove object from list based on object property

Tags: c++

my code is:

```
class Room {
public:
    int id;
    string name;
    int ownerFd;

    Room(int id, string name, int ownerFd)
    {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
        this->ownerFd = ownerFd;
    }
};

void RemoveUserRooms(int ownerFd) {
    for(auto& room : rooms) {
        if (room.ownerFd == ownerFd) {
            //remove room from list
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to remove object from list. I already tried with `remove` and `erase` but that seems not to work in this way. Is is possible to do with `list`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you remove elements from a std::list while iterating through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it)

Answer (score 2):

Use `iterator` and `erase` while properly updating the iterator.

```
    for(auto i=rooms.begin();i!=rooms.end();)
    {
        if((*i).ownerFd == ownerFd)
        i=rooms.erase(i);
        else
        i++;
    }
```

Or better ,
you can use `remove_if`

```
rooms.remove_if([ownerFd](Room i){return i.ownerFd == ownerFd;});
```

Comment: using `for` I am getting `‘room’ was not declared in this scope`, and using `remove_if`: `‘ownerFd’ is not captured`