# Why no operator+ for std::list iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, erase

I was about to write code like this:

```
std::list<whatevertype> mylist;

// ...

std::list<whatevertype>::iterator it;

for(it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it) {
    // ...
    if(some condition)
        mylist.erase(it);
}
```

But I realized, this code is wrong: `mylist.erase(x)` will invalidate the iterator `it`, so the `++it` is likely to fail.

So I tried changing it to

```
std::list<whatevertype>::iterator it;
std::list<whatevertype>::iterator nextit;

for(it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it = nextit) {
    // ...
    nextit = it + 1;
    if(some condition)
        mylist.erase(it);
}
```

But, to my surprise, this failed: evidently `operator+` is not defined for `std::list` iterators.

I've since found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162) and learned that the standard idiom for deleting "out from under" an iterator is more like

```
for(it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ) {
    if(some condition)
          it = mylist.erase(it);
    else  ++it;
}
```

I believe I could also get away with

```
for(it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ) {
    // ...
    std::list<whatevertype>::iterator previt = it;
    ++it;

    if(some condition)
        mylist.erase(previt);
}
```

But my question is, is there a reason that `operator+` is not defined for these iterators?

Comment: You get the equivalent functionality by using [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

Comment: It's probably a better idiom to use [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) than a manual loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One rule they had with the std iterators and collection was to make expensive things verbose.

On a list iterator, `it+50` takes O(50) time.  On a vector iterator, `it+50` takes O(1) time.  So they implemented `+` on vector iterators (and other random access iterators) but not on list iterators (and other weaker iterators).

`std::next` and `std::advance` and `std::prev` can solve your problem easier:

```
auto previt = std::prev(it);
```

or

```
auto nextit = std::next(it);
```

these also take a count, but because they are an explicit function call it was decided that them being expensive is acceptable.

Among other things, you can *search* for calls to `std::next` and `std::prev` and get iterator manipulation; `+` is heavily overloaded and finding the expensive calls is hard.

Note that `std::basic_string` doesn't follow the same conventions as other `std` containers.

Comment: "Make expensive things verbose".  Aha.  That's the key.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't that `+` is missing for all iterators. It is missing for `std::list` iterators.

That's because a list iterator is incredibly inefficient at random access. Therefore, making random access easy is a bad idea.

You can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). It makes it more evident that you are moving across the list one element at a time.

Comment: Question title updated in response to your first sentence, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

std::list uses a BidirectionalIterator which only defines increment and decrement. As std::list is a linked list the implementation of the iterator can only move one node at a time.

The interface is designed to make sure you know that moving by more than one element isn't a simple operation like it is with other iterators like a RandomAccessIterator returned from a std::vector.

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator for a definition of the different iterator types.