# How do I remove element pointed to by iterator in a C++ list?

Tags: c++, c++11, erase, stdlist

How do I remove element pointed to by iterator in a C++ list?  why does not this work?

```
int main()
{
    list<int> l;
    l.push_back(5);
    l.push_back(6);

    
    for(auto &it: l)
    {
        l.erase(*it);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deleting items from a `std::vector` while iterating over the items is bad. Lookup the documentation of [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) and the sample code to understand how to use it safely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you remove elements from a std::list while iterating through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it)

Comment: There's also `clear` method to remove all elements from the list.

Comment: Why does this not work: 1) In `for(auto &it: l)`, is an `int`, not an iterator, so `erase` won't accept it. B) if you did have an iterator, `erase`ing it in `list` Leaves you with an iterator to an item that's NOT in the list anymore. You can't use it to find the next item in the `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why

```
for(auto &it: l){
    l.erase(*it);
}
```

fails to work:

`it` is not an iterator. In a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), the variable declared before the colon, the *range_declaration*,  will receive an item in the container, an `int` in this case. Since `it` will receive an `int`, `auto` will infer a type of `int` resulting in

```
for(int &it: l){
    l.erase(*it);
}
```

and `std::list::erase` requires an iterator. I'm assuming the `*` is simply the result of a bit of shotgun debugging to see if dereferencing what was believed to be an iterator helped (it wouldn't).

Side note: You cannot remove an item from a container while iterating the container with a range-based for loop. The magic in the background that implements the for loop looks something like

```
{
    auto cur = container.begin() ;
    auto end = container.end();
    for ( ; cur != end; ++cur) 
    {
        auto val = *cur;
        do_stuff 
    }
}
```

If in `do_stuff` you remove `cur` from the container, `++cur` is invalid. Since `cur`'s not in the container anymore, you can't use it to advance to the next item in the container. `std::list` is very permissive in its [iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules). Many containers will fail when the cached `end` iterator is invalidated.

How to fix:

The given code appears to be trying to empty all the items in the `list`. [`std::list::clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/clear) does that for you with a single function call.

If you want to release a particular element or select elements by value, you should use [`std::list::remove` or `std::list::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) in conjunction with `std::list::erase`

eg:

```
l.erase(l.remove(5), l.end()); // remove all elements containing the number 5
```

if you want to remove the first item, [`std::list::pop_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front). To remove the last item, [`std::list::pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back). If you want to remove any other element by position, you must have a valid iterator for that position (If you do not already have one, see [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)) and then call `erase`. Note that if you're having to iterate a lot to find items to remove, `std::list` may not be the right container for this job because `list` iteration is expensive and quickly eliminates the benefits of cheap insert and removal.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted do it in loop [cpprefenrence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) has nice example

when an element removed using `erase` method, it returns the next `iterator` to removed element, if last element `end` will return;

```
std::list<int> l{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

from above list, let's assume you wanted to remove 4 and 5;

below is the way;

```
std::list<int>::iterator first = l.begin();

std::advance( first, 4 );
auto it = l.erase( first ); // removes 4 and returns iterator to element 5
l.erase( it ) // removes 5;
```

as others suggested:

```
for(auto &it: l){ // range based loop, iterating through elements ex: 4, 5, 6
  //l.erase(*it);
  std::cout << it; // prints 4, 5, 6

}
```

you need below `for loop` to increment `iterator`

```
for( auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) 
{
   // do something hear
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    list<int> l;
    list<int>::iterator it;
    l.push_back(5);
    l.push_back(6);
    l.push_back(7);
    it=l.begin();// points to the first element
    l.erase(it);//pass the iterator to the erase method
    
    for(auto i=l.begin();i!=l.end();i++){
        cout<<*i<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

lets say you want to erase the first element. Then simply pass the iterator of the list to erase method.

Answer (score -2):

If you use an iterator-based loop, you can use the return value of `erase` to update the iterator:

```
  std::list<int> l = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

  for (auto it = l.begin();
       it != l.end();
       ++it)
  {
    if (*it % 3 == 0)
    {
      it = l.erase(it);
    }
  }
  for (auto i : l)
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
```