# Can you remove elements from a std::forward_list while iterating through it?

Tags: c++, forward-list

I'm trying to *iterate through a `forward_list` **manually***, and erase certain elements.
My question is essentially the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it), but with a `forward_list` caveat.

The following code (*for example only*), despite not revisiting `before` after calling "erase after", *does not work* (it produces endless garbage).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

typedef std::forward_list<int>::iterator IT;

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<int> m{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    IT before = m.before_begin();

    for ( IT it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it;

        if ( *it % 2 == 0 )
        {
            m.erase_after( before );
        }

        before = it;
    }

    for( int i : m )
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Botje [Not really.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase_after)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, after `erase_after` the iterator to the erased element, i.e. `it` becomes invalid; performing `++it` later leads to UB.

[`erase_after`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase_after) returns the iterator to the element following the erased one, you can assign it to `it`. (And move `++it` into the `for` statement to control it manually.)

```
typedef std::forward_list<int>::iterator IT;

IT before = m.before_begin();

for ( IT it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); )
{
    std::cout << *it;

    if ( *it % 2 == 0 )
    {
        it = m.erase_after( before );
    } 
    else
    {
        before = it;
        ++it;
    }

}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VlzRRE40IpiiZHJB)