# C++ - Error while iterating std::list and deleting element

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
std::list<GameMatch*> games_;

void GameMatchManager::ClearEndedGames()
{
    if(games_.empty())
        return;

    auto it = games_.begin();
    while (it != games_.end())
    {
        auto game = *it;
        if(game->MatchEnded())
        {
            games_.erase(it);
            game->Destroy();
        }
        ++it;
    }
}

void GameMatch::Destroy()
{
    std::cout << "Destoying " << GetMatchId() << std::endl;
    delete this;
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Why am I getting this error in first place when at the top i do `if(games.empty()) return;` ?

Shouldn't that stop the iteration of `games_` list ?
Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Read about [`std::list::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase). Pay attention to what it returns. The link even contains an example that you should study.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it

Comment: You should use a regular destructor initiated via `delete` instead of whatever `Destroy` is masquerading as. Even better, if you can get rid of pointers entirely here then `erase` is all you need.

Comment: You can actually do all of this using no `while` loop and no finagling with `it` by using `stable_partition`, `for_each` and then `list::erase`, essentially 3 lines of code.

Comment: The issue is occurring because you are deleting the object `game` points to while it is still being used in the loop. After the call to`games_.erase(it);`, the iterator `it` is invalidated, meaning you can't use `it` any more. But in the next line, you increment `it` with `++it;`, which is undefined behavior since `it` has been invalidated.

Comment: @elmiomar even if I remove `game->Destroy();` again it produces same error. Any idea ?

Comment: @Venelin For the same reason that elmiomar stated. This has nothing to do with destroying game objects, and everything to do with using an iterator after it has been invalidated.

Comment: @Venelin try storing the next `it` before erasing the current one using `auto next_it = std::next(it);`, then after you call `game->Destroy();` move to the next `it` using `it = next_it;`. And add an else for `++it`.

Comment: @Venelin -- [Here is an example using what I mentioned in the comment](https://godbolt.org/z/P78cr9Wd7).

Comment: @Venelin This is how you code it correctly `if(game->MatchEnded()) { it = games_.erase(it); game->Destroy(); } else { ++it; }`

Comment: @john if I do that now I get crash on `games_.erase(it);` https://imgur.com/a/bSFOj3U

Comment: @elmiomar is it enough if I use the increase of iterator in the else as I have done in the above's comment ?

Comment: @john thank you sir. I saw the error. I forgot `it = ` on the line with `games_.erase(it);`

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem: You are using an invalid iterator. When you delete an element from a `std::list`, iterators pointing at **other** elements remain valid, but the deleted element’s iterator is in an undefined state. A possible solution is to iterate one step ahead of deletions:

```cpp
template <typename List>
void ConsumeList(List&& list) {
  auto last_it = list.begin();
  if (last_it != list.end()) {
    for (auto it = std::next(last_it); it != list.end(); ++it) {
      list.erase(last_it);  // last_it becomes invalid here.
      last_it = it;         // Never mind, we make it valid again.
    }
    list.erase(last_it);    // Don't forget this!
  }
}
```

Other notes, mostly unrelated to the problem:

0. Avoid methods such as `Destroy()`; it is likely doing something that `~GameMatch()` should be doing instead, but without strong [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)-related guarantees from the compiler. Prefer RAII over “homebrew” resource management.
1. Do **not** use raw pointers. You almost *never*(*) need them.
   (*) The only exception is when you implement low-level linked data structures. Then (and only then) it makes sense to use raw pointers.
2. Preferably, do not allocate objects directly (using smart pointers or otherwise) *at all*. Instead, let STL containers handle allocation. Embed your objects directly (`std::list<GameMatch>` instead of `std::list<GameMatch*>`). The fewer pointer jumps, the better efficiency you get.

Here’s `ConsumeList()` once again, this time in a [buildable and runnable](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Clist%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace+%7B%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+GameMatch+%7B%0D%0A++GameMatch(std%3A%3Astring_view+match_id)+%3A+match_id_%7Bmatch_id%7D+%7B%7D%0D%0A++std%3A%3Astring_view+GetMatchId()+const+%7B+return+match_id_%3B+%7D%0D%0A++%7EGameMatch()+%7B+std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Destoying+%22+%3C%3C+GetMatchId()+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B+%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A+private%3A%0D%0A++const+std%3A%3Astring+match_id_%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+List%3E%0D%0Avoid+ConsumeList(List%26%26+list)+%7B%0D%0A++auto+last_it+%3D+list.begin()%3B%0D%0A++if+(last_it+!%3D+list.end())+%7B%0D%0A++++for+(auto+it+%3D+std%3A%3Anext(last_it)%3B+it+!%3D+list.end()%3B+%2B%2Bit)+%7B%0D%0A++++++list.erase(last_it)%3B%0D%0A++++++last_it+%3D+it%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++list.erase(last_it)%3B%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D++%2F%2F+namespace%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()+%7B%0D%0A++std%3A%3Alist%3CGameMatch%3E+embedded_list%3B%0D%0A++embedded_list.emplace_back(%22Embedded+Match+A%22)%3B%0D%0A++embedded_list.emplace_back(%22Embedded+Match+B%22)%3B%0D%0A++embedded_list.emplace_back(%22Embedded+Match+C%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++std%3A%3Alist%3Cstd%3A%3Aunique_ptr%3CGameMatch%3E%3E+pointer_list%3B%0D%0A++pointer_list.emplace_back(std%3A%3Amake_unique%3CGameMatch%3E(%22Allocated+Match+A%22))%3B%0D%0A++pointer_list.emplace_back(std%3A%3Amake_unique%3CGameMatch%3E(%22Allocated+Match+B%22))%3B%0D%0A++pointer_list.emplace_back(std%3A%3Amake_unique%3CGameMatch%3E(%22Allocated+Match+C%22))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++ConsumeList(std%3A%3Amove(embedded_list))%3B%0D%0A++ConsumeList(std%3A%3Amove(pointer_list))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) context:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

namespace {

struct GameMatch {
  GameMatch(std::string_view match_id) : match_id_{match_id} {}
  std::string_view GetMatchId() const { return match_id_; }
  ~GameMatch() { std::cout << "Destoying " << GetMatchId() << std::endl; }

 private:
  const std::string match_id_;
};

template <typename List>
void ConsumeList(List&& list) {
  auto last_it = list.begin();
  if (last_it != list.end()) {
    for (auto it = std::next(last_it); it != list.end(); ++it) {
      list.erase(last_it);
      last_it = it;
    }
    list.erase(last_it);
  }
}

}  // namespace

int main() {
  std::list<GameMatch> embedded_list;
  embedded_list.emplace_back("Embedded Match A");
  embedded_list.emplace_back("Embedded Match B");
  embedded_list.emplace_back("Embedded Match C");

  std::list<std::unique_ptr<GameMatch>> pointer_list;
  pointer_list.emplace_back(std::make_unique<GameMatch>("Allocated Match A"));
  pointer_list.emplace_back(std::make_unique<GameMatch>("Allocated Match B"));
  pointer_list.emplace_back(std::make_unique<GameMatch>("Allocated Match C"));
  
  ConsumeList(std::move(embedded_list));
  ConsumeList(std::move(pointer_list));
}
```

Notice that forgetting to run `ConsumeList()` will *not* cause any memory leaks at the end and all list elements will be properly deallocated. That is the key advantage of using RAII and avoiding raw pointers.